# PHP: Is `$handle` a special variable?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand the following PHP script

```
<?php

    if ($handle = opendir('files'.'/')) {
        while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
            echo $file.'<br>';
        }
    }

?>
```

I'm not fully understanding how this works because the `$handle` variable seems either not to be declared, or to be declared inside the `if` condition.  But if it's declared inside the `if` condition, what is the condition testing for?  Similarly for the `while` loop, what is it testing for?  I know intuitively it's somehow testing for the end of the directory list, but exactly what has to happen for either the `if` condition to fail or the `while` condition to fail?  Is the use of `if` here something like an error handling method?  I looked up error handling in PHP and didn't find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, the overall value of an assignment operation is the value assigned.  What this means is that when you do this:

```
($handle = opendir('files'.'/'))
```

Not only are you assigning `$handle` to the result of `opendir()`, but the *whole statement* also evaluates to that result.

Also in PHP, any valid object is considered "truthy", so it can evaluate to `true` in a boolean check.  So this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('files'.'/'))
```

Will assign the result of `opendir()` to `$handle`, *and* will check the result of that assignment for `true` or `false`.  So if `opendir()` fails, the `if` sees a `false` and the block isn't entered.

Same for the `while`, or any other operation which examines the result of an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

In each case, the value is assigned to the variable, and then tested for truthfulness.

You could rewrite the code as:

```
$handle = opendir('files'.'/');
if ($handle) {
    $file = readdir($handle);
    while ($file) {
        echo $file.'<br>';
        $file = readdir($handle)
    }
}
```

> So, does this mean that the if condition could not possibly fail?

It will fail if `opendir()` does not return a true value. This will happen if, for example, the directory does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a coding style you can get away with in PHP

The variable is being created and evaluated in the same time in the if statement. `opendir` will return `false` if it fails and this means it code inside the `if` condition will not be run.

Generally this style not a great idea because often this kind of code is actually a bug where it was meant to be an `==`, eg `if($variable=true)` and `if($variable==true)` are vastly different but not necessarily easy to spot if you are scanning through the code.

the use of `$file =` in the while loop though is quite a normal approach and is used to iterate over something.

`readdir` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php - is iterable and so can be used in this style

Comment: So, does this mean that the `if` condition could not possibly fail?

Comment: Also, I had read that documentation on the `readdir` function but it still wasn't clear to me what's going on.  This looks like using a `while` loop where a `for` loop should be used.

Comment: opendir can return false and in that case it would fail